# Showing a Particular Function Between Two Metric Spaces is Continuous

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$\fbox{Hypothesis}$

Suppose $(M,d)$ is embedded densely into the two complete metric spaces $(M', d')$ and $(M'', d'')$.

Suppose we define $\rho: M \rightarrow M''$ as the identity mapping.

$\fbox{Definition}$

Now we will extend $\rho$ by defining $\bar{\rho}: M' \rightarrow M''$ as $\bar{\rho}(x) = x$ if $x \in M$, otherwise we pick an arbitrary sequence $x_n$ in $M$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow x$ and define $\bar{\rho}(x) = \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \{\rho (x_n)\}$.

$\fbox{Unproven Facts About $\bar{\rho}$ }$

I have already shown the following about $\bar{\rho}$:

1. It is well-defined.
2. It is isometric.

$\fbox{Question}$ Why is $\bar{\rho}$ continuous?

$\fbox{Attempted Answer}$

If $\{x_n\} \subseteq M$, then $\underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \bar{\rho}(x_n) = \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \rho (x_n) = \bar{\rho}(x)$.  However I'm not sure how to show the case when $\{x_n\} \not\subseteq M$.

Comment: Aren't isometric functions always continuous?

Comment: I think you made a typo in your definition.  It should probably read "otherwise we pick an arbitrary sequence $x_n$ in $M$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow x$ and define $\bar{\rho}(x) = \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim} \{\rho (x_n)\}$."

Comment: FiveLemmon -- definition corrected.
hot_queen -- that could be an easier way of going about this.

Comment: If $x_n \in M$ then you don't need to handle the case that $\{x_n\} \not\subset M$.